# linq: check if there are entries from the same day or week in a particular table

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

so what I want to do is get the number of entries in the database that are form a selected date and from the week that day was in. Both the database column and my variable are datetime fields.
my method for the date is:

```
private int multiUse_timesInADay()
    {
           daydate date = currentDate.date;
        var submitCount = from campaignMessages in dcCRData.Mytable
                          where  campaignMessages.Created == date 
                          select campaignMessages;
        int count = submitCount.Count();

        return count;
    }
```

and I'm kinda lost on how to do the week search.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//first get to the last monday i.e. start of the week

int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - currentDate.date.DayOfWeek;
DateTime monday = currentDate.date.AddDays(delta);


var submitCount = from campaignMessages in dcCRData.Mytable
                  where  campaignMessages.Created >= monday &&  campaignMessages.Created <= monday.AddDays(7)    
                  select campaignMessages;
```